# How can I see which switchports are not in use?

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, cisco-commands, cisco-ios

On a large Cisco Catalyst switch stack, almost all switchports are patched. I need to identify the ports, which are not in use, for connecting further devices.

Following switchports, cabling, patch fields and sockets to possible end devices is laborious and even then there could be temporarily used sockets. Looking at the activity of port LEDs is not reliable, since a user device can be shut off.

What's the easiest way to detect all unused switchports via IOS commands?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I frequently use

```
sh int | i (FastEthernet|0 packets input)
```

or the same with GigabitEthernet, whatever kind of interfaces I want to check.

- `sh int` (which is `show interfaces`) gives a huge list of ste status of all interfaces
- The pipe symbol `|` can be used for filtering, but also in search expressions
- `| i` (for `include`) filters the output which matches the following search expressions
- I use `(...|...)` to match two conditions: the interface name and a status I like to see, we can use regular expressions here, like this "or" expression

The output can look like:

```
...
FastEthernet1/0/31 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
     95445640 packets input, 18990165053 bytes, 0 no buffer
FastEthernet1/0/32 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
FastEthernet1/0/33 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
FastEthernet1/0/34 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect)
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 no buffer
FastEthernet1/0/35 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect)
FastEthernet1/0/36 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
FastEthernet1/0/37 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect)
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 no buffer
...
```

Now I can see my candidates, with actually 0 packets input over time, even if my expression matches numbers just ending with 0. I could make it more perfect, but being easy to remember is also a benefit. The interface names right before each 0 packets input lines are my candidates.

- Check each chosen interface if it's really unused by `sh int <name>`
- From time to time, it's good to clear the counters: `clear counters [type number]`

It can be good practice, to leave unused switchports shutdown. So it's easy to identify them using `sh ip int bri` or the like. And you don't run into problems if you use a switchport which was definitly shut off before.

Comment: Device#Show int | i notconnect  will show just the interfaces that are down/down.

Comment: This answer is "Network Engineer 1.0" style. Seriously? Pipe to include? :)   Instead, pull the data off the device and process it with standard UNIX tools and write your own script/program to produce a report.

Comment: @stefan, parenthesis are not required... this works just fine in ios: `sh int | i FastEthernet|0 packets input`

Comment: Also, if you remove the "Fast" part you'll match Gig, Fast and regular Ethernet interfaces

Answer (score 29):

Ultimately... DOCUMENTATION.  You need to know where every patch cable goes to be 100% certain you aren't disconnecting something someone may expect to work at some point.  Just because a port is currently "down" doesn't mean someone has not been using it.  Also just because the counters are currently zero doesn't mean it's never been used or not going to be used again in the (near) future -- counters can be cleared, and counters reset to zero at boot.

I've worked at ISPs and large enterprises, and documentation is the key to knowing what's what.  Without it, random guessing will lead to numerous bad days... customers get rather pissed when you run their DSL line to someone else, duplicate an address assignment, shutdown the wrong interface, etc.  Enterprise wiring closets can be a real mess; without documentation, tracing dozens of cables among thousands can be a pain (and something as simple as port descriptions count.)

Comment: I agree, documentation is absolutely important and I document patching and port configs. Just in huge offices where 98% of the ports are of the same standard config, and the working places rapidly change, and the patching is done by 1st level sevice desk, I cannot safely document, so I need checks what is used at all. Of course non-standard ports won't be touched without documenting.

Comment: Have to down vote this one (I think it's my first..) this question is more about the "what can I audit now" versus "what do I think I have?"  Documentation is great. Sometimes, irrelevant.

Comment: "**for connecting further devices**" so he's looking for free ports to use elsewhere, not auditing his infrastructure.  Proper documentation is the only way to know for sure, short of that... trace the cable (which he said was a major pain.)

Comment: Documentation is great and immensely helpful when you have it.  However, sometimes you "inherit" a network with little or no documentation and no means to gather it.  As an example, one network I worked on had thousands of switch ports and in one building the patch panels were labelled "Bob M.", "Sally J.", etc.  Sometimes you just need to forge ahead with the information you can gather (and wish you had documentation).

Comment: Documentation isn't always 100% accurate either. But at the end of the day, there's your docs and there's tracing the port all the way to the end.  There have been may approaches offered for detecting recent activity (where recent is since a counter zeroing event), but you still risk reusing a port someone may assume is still connected.  I've been bitten reusing ports I thought people weren't using anymore -- Murphy's law.

Comment: I agree with documentation and also placing useful description on the switch-ports. In perhaps one of the largest Unis that I have worked, the staff are always moving form one building to another. Amongst doing other things, Statseeker was used to poll the ports and we could then go back in time to ascertain which ports have not been used for 3 months or more towards reclaiming them.

Answer (score 12):

I also like

```
sh int | inc line protocol is|Last input
```

which outputs

```
FastEthernet0/29 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect)
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
FastEthernet0/30 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
  Last input never, output 00:00:07, output hang never
FastEthernet0/46 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect)
  Last input never, output 6d23h, output hang never
```

The output parameter tells you when the port last saw traffic which is useful for identifying those ports that are only occasionally used.

EDIT: Also worth noting (for reasons beyond the scope of this question) is that "Last input" is almost always "never"

Comment: I liked this until I tried it out and noticed that the management interface on my primary F5 says "Last input never" but also shows "136217193 packets input".  I was just in that F5 a few minutes ago so I'm pretty confident that interface is in use and working.

Comment: Good point, I added an edit to clarify. This is expected behavior.  As well, I opened a new question (http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-does-show-interface-show-last-input-never-when-packets-input-is-incremen) to address your point.

Comment: @MikeMarotta So from this, can we deduce that this command is in fact no good because the results are unreliable?

Comment: While last input is almost always never, the output value should be what you are looking at and this does grab the line.

Answer (score 11):

I like @Stefan's answer but with this command line "sh int | i (Ethernet| 0 packets input)" which now grabs all Ethernet interface types and filters out non-zero numbers that happen to end in zero.  He mentioned that some fine tuning might be possible so this is just one example.

Another option is...

```
  sh int counters | i (Port|_0             0             0             0)
```

Yes, the whitespace is needed. The easiest way to get the spaces right is do "sh int counters" and copy a line with all zeros. One gotcha here is that half-way down the list changes from Input, which we want, to Output, which we don't care about for finding unused ports.  It has the advantage of showing ONLY the ports with no input so you don't have to weed out the in-use ports like you do with Stefan's method.

Comment: Use awk. Don't worry about crazy spaces.

Comment: I don't believe awk is available at the IOS CLI.  If it is then I'm mad that I didn't about it as would certainly be handy.

Comment: See my answer. My point is that you should pull the info off the device (via SNMP or other) or copy paste this output to your favorite UNIX box and do the work there. The whole world is then available.

Comment: I generally pull it back to EditPad Pro as it does the best regex I've seen in a Windows text editor.  Awk, sed and all of that are also useful but I was getting as targeted as possible just in the CLI.

Comment: +1, Technically you could use `show int counters | i _0_.*_0_.*_0_.*_0_` instead of spaces... also your answer needs to be `sh int counters | i (Port|_0             0             0             0)` (note the leading underscore, which IOS interprets as a space)

Comment: Thank you for that.  I didn't know about the underscore.  I think I started pulling the actual spaces because there's another show counters that has five columns and I was matching lines with four zeros and a number. I do remember that I tried shortening it and for whatever I was doing at the time it was easier to just copy a line with all zeros.

Comment: Proper regex is supported on recent IOS versions (i tried this on a 3560 on 12.2(55)SE7), so the simplest working regex to do what you're suggesting would be `show interfaces counters | inc ( +0 +0 +0)`.

Answer (score 11):

I would scrape the output (or grab it with SNMP, even better) and use standard UNIX tools to parse it.  Here's an easy example:

Here, I saved a partial output from 'show int counters' (just for demo purposes) to a file called "counters".

```
[mkantows@ochofu049]$ cat counters
Port            InOctets    InUcastPkts    InMcastPkts    InBcastPkts
Gi1/0/1                0              0              0              0
Gi1/0/2      94949242720      556137619         571828          57745
Gi1/0/3       1522191492        8663327        1105299          55269
Gi1/0/4       3743856345       18565173        1275617          53658
Gi1/0/5                0              0              0              0
Gi1/0/6                0              0              0              0
```

Now, just use awk to produce a report of all ports that have all four counter fields at zero:

```
[mkantows@ochofu049]$ cat counters | awk '{if ($2 == 0 && $3 == 0 && $4 == 0 && $5 == 0) print $1}'
Gi1/0/1
Gi1/0/5
Gi1/0/6
```

The main idea here is to get whatever data you are using off of the device so you can do more intelligent/complex/simpler/whatever parsing and reporting.

**NOTE** For multiple devices, using a Linux utility like "screen" to log output from a tty connection can make it really efficient for quickly finding unused ports on multiple cisco devices.  (in one log file)
run a command like the following...    where "HOSTNAME" is a universal part of your Cisco device hostname scheme
cat counters | awk '{if ($1 == *HOSTNAME*) || ($2 == 0 && $3 == 0 && $4 == 0 && $5 == 0) print $1}'

Comment: Nice! Sometimes it's also easy to pipe the file through `grep` and `sed`.

Comment: Exactly - whatever standard UNIX tools get the job done.  The main point is "don't do it on the router, that's too painful" :)

Comment: I won't downvote, but you really should investigate IOS regular expressions... the CLI I include at the end of the comment is much easier than sucking CLI onto a unix machine and then using some awk incantation... `show int counters | i _0_.*_0_.*_0_.*_0_`

Answer (score 7):

I'm new so I can't vote up @netdad's and @mike pennington's answers - but I like them.  To take @Mike Pennington's answer a little further, assuming you've cleared the counters recently, you could run this command also:

```
switch#sh int count | i 0 +0 + 0 +0
Gi1/3                       0             0             0             0
Gi1/11                      0             0             0             0
Gi1/19                      0             0             0             0
Gi1/21                      0             0             0             0
```

The regex here is saying a "0" followed by 1 or more spaces followed by a "0" followed by 1 or more spaces followed by a "0" followed by 1 or more spaces followed by a final "0".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

I always use

```
show interfaces status
```

It sums it al up nice and dandy.

Comment: Sure, that's a nice overview, but as it doesn't show packet counters we cannot see if a device is just powered off or disconnected, but the port may be in use from time to time. Could be a surprise for that user if I used the port for a different purpose just because it was down or notconnected at that time.

Comment: Aah ok see what you meen... I clear the counters every year .. So for me in yhis case a sh int counters works fine but you have to clear your counters every now and then ...

Comment: I like to add `| ex connected` to that.

Answer (score 5):

I typically use `sh int des | ex up`, which will list all the ports that are in a down state

Comment: Works, but i have to say i find the output of `show interfaces status` more helpful.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to do this regularly, nothing beats Perl and Net::Telnet::Cisco.  You can log into X number of routers, grab all of the information on the interfaces you want, parse the output, and print it to a file or e-mail it with Net::SMTP or print it to standard output.  I can provide examples if you want, but it's pretty straightforward.

Alternatively, if you are dead set on doing this within IOS, the following TCL script will give you the output you want in a nice, clean format:

```
set show_counters [exec show interfaces counters | i 0 +0 +0 +0]
set line [split $show_counters "\n"]
foreach record $line {
    set fields [join $record " "]
    foreach field $fields {
        if { $field != 0 } {
            puts $field
        }
    }
}
```

I offer this because TCL and how to do this is a little less accessible [IMHO] than Perl

Answer (score 4):

Here's one I've been using recently to remove cables from ports that haven't seen any activity for at least six weeks:

```
show int | i proto.*notconnect|proto.*administratively down|Last in.* [6-9]w|Last in.*
[0-9][0-9]w|[0-9]y|disabled|Last input never, output never, output hang never
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 sh int | in is down|input never, output never

FastEthernet0 is administratively down, line protocol is down 
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
GigabitEthernet1/0/2 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect) 
GigabitEthernet1/0/4 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect) 
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
GigabitEthernet1/0/13 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect) 
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
GigabitEthernet1/0/24 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect) 
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
```

Comment: You can easily this to *sh int | in (is down|output never)* which is much easier to type and will give the same result.

Answer (score 3):

```
sh int | i ( 0 packets input)|proto|Desc
```

*The leading space with the 0 will exclude larger numbers that end in zero.*

It's better to have ports shutdown (disabled) until they get used.  It's risky to change *switchport access vlan*, for example, on a port that's already up unless you can be certain it's not in use.

Output might look like below, telling us that the switchport on g8/18 is disabled with 0 packets since last counter clear while g8/19 is in use (from the absence of the "0 packets input").

```
GigabitEthernet8/18 is administratively down, line protocol is down (disabled)
  Description: 3a30
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 no buffer
GigabitEthernet8/19 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
  Description: 4a25.vmhost112 (vmnic5)
```

> As for knowing which patch panel jack is involved, use the Description
>   field to help you document.  Patch panels should be connected to
>   switchports in a consistent manner, so it's easy to document as the patch panel jack to switchport is predictable.  I use
>   the format *Rack-Row-Jack* in the description + the hostname to track,
>   but in a condensed way.  4b27 would be row rack 4, row b, jack 27
>   followed by hostxyz or whatever the hostname.  So my descripton reads
>   4b27.hostxyz.

Answer (score 3):

What about using the MAC table?  It lists the MAC addresses with the interfaces and it ages them out. You would have to take the list out of IOS to do a filtered list of unique addresses.

Answer (score 2):

OK. Something that works on all switches starting from 2900 (don't have older to test) and shows only down ports.

```
sh int | i is down
```

I'd love to use `sh int status` but after that the result is `connected` and `notconnected`, so exclude or include don't do any good because the word connected is part of both, so you get the story.

In my case on a 3524 I get that below with both commands in order to make clear it works:

```
SD-LIB-C3524#sh int status

Port    Name               Status       Vlan     Duplex Speed   Type
------- ------------------ ------------ -------- ------ ------- ----
Fa0/1                      notconnect   10         Auto    Auto 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/2                      notconnect   10         Auto    Auto 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/3                      connected    10       A-Full   A-100 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/4                      notconnect   10         Auto    Auto 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/5                      notconnect   10         Auto    Auto 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/6                      notconnect   10         Auto    Auto 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/7                      notconnect   10         Auto    Auto 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/8                      notconnect   10         Auto    Auto 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/9                      connected    10       A-Full   A-100 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/10                     notconnect   10         Auto    Auto 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/11                     connected    10       A-Full   A-100 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/12                     connected    10       A-Full   A-100 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/13  WiFi SD-LIB-15     connected    40       A-Full   A-100 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/14  WiFi SD-LIB-22     connected    40       A-Full   A-100 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/15  WiFi SD-LIB-16     connected    40       A-Full   A-100 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/16  WiFi SD-LIB-23     connected    40       A-Full   A-100 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/17  WiFi SD-LIB-17     connected    40       A-Full   A-100 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/18  WiFi SD-LIB-24     connected    40       A-Full   A-100 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/19  WiFi SD-LIB-18     connected    40       A-Full   A-100 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/20  WiFi SD-LIB-14     connected    40       A-Full   A-100 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/21  WiFi SD-LIB-19     connected    40       A-Full   A-100 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/22  WiFi SD-LIB-21     connected    40       A-Full   A-100 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/23  WiFi SD-LIB-20     connected    40       A-Full   A-100 100BaseTX/FX
Fa0/24  SD-LIB-3C4500-50P  connected    trunk    A-Full   A-100 100BaseTX/FX
Gi0/1                      notconnect   trunk      Auto    1000 Missing
Gi0/2                      notconnect   10         Auto    1000 Missing
```

---

```
SD-LIB-C3524#sh int | i is down
VLAN1 is up, line protocol is down
FastEthernet0/1 is down, line protocol is down
FastEthernet0/2 is down, line protocol is down
FastEthernet0/4 is down, line protocol is down
FastEthernet0/5 is down, line protocol is down
FastEthernet0/6 is down, line protocol is down
FastEthernet0/7 is down, line protocol is down
FastEthernet0/8 is down, line protocol is down
FastEthernet0/10 is down, line protocol is down
GigabitEthernet0/1 is down, line protocol is down
GigabitEthernet0/2 is down, line protocol is down
SD-LIB-C3524#
```

Comment: Correction, *connect* is part of both, but you can exclude *connected* to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit cheating, but if everything is only attached to one end device, you can turn on port security with sticky mac addresses.  Check back in a while (however long you expect is a reasonable amount of time to assume that someone would have used the computer or it doesn't exist) and the running config will show you if anything has used that port.  I'm pretty sure you can use sticky mac addresses with a max of more than 1 per interface just in case you're using VoIP phones and computers on the same port, but I'm not certain.

Comment: I don't remember the command but you can definitely set the max MACs to more than one.

Comment: Under the interface, "switchport port-security maximum 2" or whatever number you care to permit.

Comment: I know you can change the maximum allowable mac addresses with port security, I just didn't know if you could learn more than one through sticky.

Answer (score 1):

```
test cable diagnostics tdr interface *intname here*
```

This should show you whether or not the cable attached to the switchport is actually connected to anything. Regardless of its status.
Replace `test` with `show` to get the status.

Comment: This really isn't any different than `show int status`.  If I've unplugged my laptop to go home for the day, then my port may be reassigned by morning.

Answer (score 1):

Oh the days when it was easy just to type:

```
switch 1#show ver | in uptime
switch 1 uptime is 28 weeks, 6 days, 20 hours, 19 minutes

switch 1#show inter link | in 28 weeks
Fa3/1                      28 weeks, 6 days, 20 hours, 19 minutes 16 secs
Fa3/2                      28 weeks, 6 days, 20 hours, 19 minutes 16 secs
```

(that's on a 4500 running version 12.2(20))

Answer (score 1):

I think that in Cisco environment the best way is to a **show version** to know the uptime of the switch and after

**show interfaces accounting**

```
Interface Vlan1 is disabled
Vlan810 
            Protocol    Pkts In   Chars In   Pkts Out  Chars Out
                  IP     709229   73055034     232297   33127143
                 ARP        738      44280         70       4200
FastEthernet0/1 
            Protocol    Pkts In   Chars In   Pkts Out  Chars Out
No traffic sent or received on this interface.

FastEthernet0/2 
            Protocol    Pkts In   Chars In   Pkts Out  Chars Out
               Other          0          0         19       6669
       Spanning Tree          0          0      18588    1115280
                 CDP          0          0        658     309918
```

Comment: Which fields are you specifically saying should be considered and how does that help to know if switchports are in use or not?

Answer (score 1):

only using IOS commands is a bit tricky - you will miss out the odd one.
I'd suggest like others to use snmp (solarwinds has a number of free tools you might want to look at) and to monitor the device for a number of days (weeks if necessary)

For the laborious part you mentioned with tracing cables etc. 
What I did to minimize the work with mapping switch ports to patch ports etc. was clearing the counters and then a few days later using snmp traps and then unplugging on the patchpanel for 1-2 seconds and once I got an entry on the snmp trap monitor/receiver (port x on module y went down), I just did the same thing again to verify (not that someone just incidentially turned off a device on one of the ports).
It takes maybe 5 minutes for a 24 port panel - so this is rather quick. For the dead ones - just go back another time. If they are still dead, and no change on the counters then it is safe to assume the port is actually not in use.

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem at our firm. We used correlation from the output of "show arp" and "show mac address-table" commands to correlate the MAC Addresses of all the computers/devices in our premisses.

First you will need to make a list of the IPs and MACs of the devices in your network, and correlate them with the corresponding interfaces using the above commands...

Answer (score 1):

I usually use "show interface status" and variations on it but I also use a neat piece of open-source software called "Switchmap" to provide a simple graphical view of the interfaces. One great benefit of this is that if a port is up/down it will tell you how long ago it last had traffic on it and you can make a call from there as whether you should reuse it or not.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/switchmap/

This saves some typing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Show IP interface brief is my personal favourite.

Makes it slightly easier for you to view. If not there are plenty of tools out there to help track port usage across many switches.

Answer (score 0):

On Cisco devices, you can use;

```
sh int status
```

Whilst on HP devices, the command is;

```
sh int brief
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for a sum of based on the status? at least it sounds like your question.

```
show interfaces status | count notconnect|connected
```

give you a nice count of what is either connected or not.

Comment: The OP seems to specifically ask which switchports are not in use so he can connect new devices to it, not how many are unused.