# Show interfaces link equivalent

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-commands

On Catalyst 4500, there is the command show int link which outputs:

```
    Fa1/1    UPS               00 secs
    Fa1/2    Data & Voice      00 secs
    Fa1/3    Data & Voice      00 secs
    Fa1/4    Data & Voice      00 secs

<output continues>....
    Fa3/18   Data & Voice      13 hours, 13 minutes 58 secs      13:47:23  Tue Mar 25 2014
```

But when I try this command on a 3560 i get:

```
Switch#show int link
                 ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

Is there an equivalent on the 3560 or 3750 switch for finding such information as the last time the port was active?
My goal is to find which switchports have not been active for a long time and can have their cable disconnected from the switchport to save room for other devices to use in the future.

Comment: Take a look at the previously answered question, [How can I see which switchports are not in use](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-i-see-which-switchports-are-not-in-use).  It may help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
show int | i Ethernet|Last input

GigabitEthernet6/1 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
  Last input 00:00:03, output 00:00:52, output hang never
GigabitEthernet6/2 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
  Last input 00:00:26, output 00:00:00, output hang never
GigabitEthernet6/3 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
  Last input 00:00:08, output 00:00:08, output hang never
GigabitEthernet6/4 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
```

Comment: Just a warning with this command, it is not fool-proof.  As noted in [this question, those counters don't always work.](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-does-show-interface-show-last-input-never-when-packets-input-is-incremen?rq=1).